# Inset rounded edges with CSS

Tags: css, curves

Is it possible to do this kind of thing with CSS?

[image]

From my Googling, I can't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with CSS3's radial gradients:

[image]

CSS:

```
div{
  background: 
    radial-gradient(
      circle at -40px 50px, 
      transparent 80px,
      red 80px
    );
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
body { background-color: blue; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7WHAz/2/

Comment: much better than my solution indeed. but it won't work with old browsers. I would use an image if aiming for all browsers as, sadly, mayoritie of my clients ask for.

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez Good point. [Browser support](http://caniuse.com/css-gradients) is decent at 78%, working in most browsers except for IE as usual.

Comment: Very interesting. Wish I had seen it sooner. will definitely use on a future project.

Answer (score 2):

this may work... but just if a plain background color I'm afraid:

http://jsfiddle.net/7WHAz/

change the:

```
 div:before {        
    background-color:white; 
}
```

to the color your background use

Comment: Sadly, I need it to work on against an image. Good answer, I'll just have to use images.

Comment: There's no problem using images... just add the image at the left of your div insteed of a full image as container. in this example the png size is just 3kb: http://jsfiddle.net/7WHAz/1/